# jQuery using .html() but needing to exclude an element

Tags: jquery

I'm using `.html()` to pull a list of `<li>`'s from a `div` but I need to exclude the `li` with the `id` of `#donate-link`

At current my jQuery is

```
var _topbarmenu = $("<div/>").attr({
        "id": "topbarmenu",
        }).append($('.tabs').html())
        .prepend("<li id='shop-link'>"+_pm+"</li>");
```

As you can see I'm pulling the data in using `$('.tabs').html()` and I have tried `$('.tabs').html().not('#donate-link')` but this does not seem to work .

**EDIT EXTRA CONTENT**

```
var _topbarmenucontent = $('#header .tabs').html();
$(_topbarmenucontent).find('#donate-link').remove();
var _topbarmenu = $("<div/>").attr({
    "id": "topbarmenu",
    })  .append(_topbarmenucontent)
        .prepend("<li id='shop-link'>"+_pm+"</li>");
var _topcontent = $("<div/>").append(_topbarlogo).append(_topbarmenu);
$(_topbar).append(_topcontent);

$("#wrap").prepend(_topbar);
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 170) {
        console.log('>10');
        $(_topbar).slideDown();
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        console.log('0');
        $(_topbar).slideUp();
    } else {
        console.log('0');
        $(_topbar).slideUp();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="shop-link" class="garage-link"><a href="/board" class="mainmenu" original-title="Visit the Board"><span>Board</span></a></li>
        <li id="shop-link" class="garage-link"><a href="./garage.php" class="mainmenu" original-title="Visit the Virtual Garage"><span>Garage <i>[BETA]</i></span></a></li>
        <li id="shop-link" class="upload-an-image"><a href="#" original-title="Upload an Image"><span>Upload Image</span></a></li>
        <li id="shop-link"><a href="/board/merch" original-title="Purchase items from Enthst Store"><span>Store</span></a></li>
        <li id="members-link"><a href="./memberlist.php" original-title="View complete list of members"><span>Members</span></a></li>
        <li id="donate-link"> <a href="#" target="_blank" original-title="Donate"><span>Donate</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

**EDIT JSFIDDLE ADDED**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VkHz9/1/)

Comment: @billyonecan the element still appears as normal

Comment: @billyonecan You're throwing away rep points, this could've been an answer, if expanded a bit..

Comment: because .html() doesnot return object so you can't place jquery chaining here.

Comment: @maverickosama92 is there a work around?

Comment: i think this could work: .append($('.tabs:not(#donate-link)').html()) , but again its just a wild guess not tested.

Comment: Is there are reason you use the HTML instead of the DOM nodes?

Comment: @FelixKling I looked at an option to just get the `li`'s of my `ul` into where I needed and `.html()` is what I thought was the best way? I seem mistaken

Comment: Once the browser parsed the HTML and you are accessing the DOM with JavaScript, it's usually easier to work with DOM elements, instead of serializing them back to HTML. You also avoid unexpected behavior, like loss of event handlers and data, which occurs because parsing the HTML to DOM creates *new* elements.

Comment: I have saved it into a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VkHz9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have just sussed it out by using `$('#header .tabs').clone().not('#donate-link')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`$('.tabs').not('#donate-link').html()`

Your code didn't work because html returns a string not a jQuery object that can be chained.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need the contents of $('.tabs') without the element itself:

```
.append($('.tabs').children().not('#donate-link'));
```

You don't necessarily have to append the .html() string, you can use the jQuery object itself.

Answer (score 0):

The selector part gets the toplevel element, it's HTML includes the child nodes implicitly. What you want is to clone the HTML (by wrapping in another `$()`), drill down to the "bad" element, remove it, then call `.end()` to go back to the cloned `.tabs` with the `#donate-link` now excluded. Something like `.append($($(".tabs").html()).find("#donate-link").remove().end())`

Answer (score 0):

i think this could work:

```
 .append($('.tabs:not(#donate-link)').html());
```

but again its just a wild guess not tested